# Adobe Air vertical scroll for rich text

Tags: actionscript-3, air, scrollbar, richtext, vertical-scrolling

I have a rich text component with large amount of text. How to add vertical scrollbar to it?

I tried:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%" verticalScrollBar="vsb">
    <s:RichText id="text" width="100%" height="100%" maxDisplayedLines="-1"/>
</mx:Canvas>
<s:VScrollBar id="vsb" height="100%"/>
```

But it get error: Initializer for 'verticalScrollBar': values of type mx.controls.scrollClasses.ScrollBar cannot be represented in text.

Comment: Can you include the source code that shows what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [docs on RichText](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/RichText.html), I see this:

> For performance reasons, it does not
>   support scrolling, selection, editing,
>   clickable hyperlinks, or images loaded
>   from URLs. If you need those
>   capabilities, please see the
>   RichEditableText class.

So, going with a RichEditableText (and setting its `editable` property to `false`, this works for me with FlashBuilder 4.5.   **Note:** I set the Scroller height to **200** and added lots of text to force a scrollbar to appear)

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">  
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="200">
       <s:RichEditableText percentWidth="100" percentHeight="100" editable="false">
      <!-- add lots of text here to introduce a scrollbar -->       
       </s:RichEditableText>
    </s:Scroller>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you told me - is it possible to change visual style of this scroller (another images to up/down buttons).